# Count length of string inside array

Tags: php, arrays, string-length

How is the way to count length of string in array:

```
$mainArray = [
    [4],
    [3, 4],
    [2, 30, 43, 65, 53, 634]];
```

Output desired:

```
1
1,1
1,2,2,2,2,3
```

My ideia is change to string use string count function, but have the way to do direct on array?

Comment: You can use $mainArray[i]/10 instead. So if($mainArray[i]/10 ==0) echo 1, if($mainArray[i]/10 >0 && $mainArray[i]/10 <9) echo 2... etc
(you can use a switch statement, but the range of integers should be limited!)

Comment: what are you actually doing(just curious)? your last 3 questions have been about the same array but all different?

Comment: To long to explain here... @smith

Comment: The answers below are confused about your desired output.  Do you want an array of arrays containing the string lengths, or do you want 3 printed lines of comma-separated strings?  Your desired output is Unclear.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has an `array_map()` which can help you to do this.

```
function countString($s) {
    return strlen((string)$s);
}

function countArray($arr) {
    return array_map("countString", $arr);
}

$result = array_map("countArray", $mainArray);
```

Well honestly I do think using two loops would be much easier and clearer...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map()` with builtin functions `implode` and `strlen`:

```
$mainArray = [
[4],
[3, 4],
[2, 30, 43, 65, 53, 634]];
print_r(array_map(function ($v) { 
                    return implode(',', array_map('strlen', $v));
                  },
                  $mainArray));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1,1
    [2] => 1,2,2,2,2,3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$mainArray = [
[4],
[3, 4],
[2, 30, 43, 65, 53, 634]];
foreach($mainArray as $key => $element):
    foreach($element as $ele):
        $eleString =  countString($ele);
        if(count($element)>1) $eleString .= ',';
            echo $eleString;
    endforeach;
    echo '<br/>';
 endforeach;

 function countString($s) {
    return strlen((string)$s);
 }
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.